# How to best handle dropdowns (select menus)?

Tags: css, html, mobile, responsive-design

I wonder as of today, what is the best approach to handle select menus for mobile web apps? I'm especially talking about the picker (e.g. what happens when you click on the select menu to choose a value)

I know that for instance jquery mobile shows a nicely styled select menu replacement but once you click on it it opens the native picker. Or at least, that's the default behaviour you can also make it open a non-native jquery mobile controlled list.

But I wonder, when you use the default behaviour that opens the native picker, does that give desireable results on all plattforms? Isn't it that some early versions of some plattforms don't have a nice usable picker for `<select>`elements?

I see more and more people just using the native picker with some styling around the `<select>` menu and I really like it. I just wonder is it already save to do so or are the plattforms where that leaves us undesireable results?

Comment: I prefered the native way, if I could choose. It is more familiar to the user, because native and framework implementations differ so much.

Comment: Me, too. I just wonder wasn't it that some early platform versions (e.g. early `Androids`) didn't have a nice native picker?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the native select box. That method has been implemented, tested and approved by the browser maker on whichever device it happens to run on. Once you circumvent their decisions, you're on your own.

#### However

If you're pretty confident in your user base and you know the market you want to hit, it can often be implemented with much better usability for your case, groupings scroll, alphabetical jumping etc.

Just as long as you can test on 99.999% of your users devices there shouldn't be a problem implementing your own.

Comment: I agree. I just wonder wasn't it that some early platform versions (e.g. early `Androids`) didn't have a nice native picker?

Comment: I see. Well I've only got a limited scope but in my experience the user base is just too small to matter. That's a personal call from project to project though. For me Android < 2.3 is only in double digits per month. Other platforms are even less.